# Solution to $AB=BA$ given $B$ a $2\times 2$ matrix and non singular?

Tags: matrices

If $AB=BA$  given $B$ is non singular and a two dimensional matrix can we conclude that  $A$ is either a scalar multiple of $B^{-1}$  or a scalar multiple of identity $I$  or a linear combination of the two ?

Comment: At least you have to assume $B\ne I$.

Comment: yeah absolutely that is a given B is not equal to I !

Comment: Well A = B obviously satisfies the condition. now this works for any B so in particular B doesn't have to be multiple of $B^{-1}$ or identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume $B$ is not scalar, otherwise any matrix $A$ will satisfy the identity. For a fixed $B$, consider the linear map
$$
f(A)=AB-BA
$$
from the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices to itself. Since $B$ is not scalar, there is a matrix $A$ not commuting with $B$, so the rank of $f$ is at least $1$.

The matrices $I$, $B$ belong to the kernel of $f$ and are linearly independent. Let's compute $f$ on the standard matrices
$$
E_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad
E_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\quad
E_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\quad
E_4=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
We have
$$
f(E_1)=\begin{bmatrix}0&b\\-c&0\end{bmatrix},
f(E_2)=\begin{bmatrix}c&-a+d\\0&-c\end{bmatrix},
f(E_3)=\begin{bmatrix}-b&0\\a-d&b\end{bmatrix},
f(E_4)=\begin{bmatrix}0&-b\\c&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the rank of $f$ is the same as the rank of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b & -c & 0 \\
c & -a+d & 0 & -c \\
-b & 0 & a-d & b \\
0 & -b & c & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $B=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$.

It is not difficult to show that the rank of the matrix is $2$ if either $b\ne0$ or $c\ne0$: just consider the top right or bottom left $2\times2$ minors. If $b=c=0$, then we know that $a\ne d$, so again the rank is $2$, by considering the central $2\times2$ minor.

Thus any matrix in the kernel is a linear combination of $I$ and $B$, or of $I$ and $B^{-1}$, because also $I$ and $B^{-1}$ are linearly independent and in the kernel.

Comment: Mighty Nice thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

No, we have the subgroup of $GL_2$ of matrices of the form

$\left(\begin{array}[cc]\\ 1&x\\0&1
\end{array}\right).$

This is a collection of commuting invertible matrices, so for any $A, B$ of this form, we have $AB=BA$, with $B$ nonsingular. But $A$ is not a scalar multiple of $B^{-1}$ nor a scalar matrix.

Edit: Given the motivation mentioned, I suggest working out what must be true with coordinates:

$B = \left(\begin{array}[cc]\\ a&b\\c&d
\end{array}\right), 
A = \left(\begin{array}[cc]\\ x&y\\z&w
\end{array}\right) $,
and work out what must be true of $A$.

Comment: Can this come under the linear combination of the two solutions ?

Comment: Sure, if you are taking coefficients in a field. Otherwise, no. but now I am confused about the motivation. This is a relation about commuting matrices. Why do you care about linear combinations?

Comment: @WAL well i have to find the dimension and the basis of the subspace produced , which is the motivation .

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are of that form and $B\ne I$, then it is true that $A$ is a linear combination of the identity and of $B^{-1}$.

Comment: @egreg other than taking a variable matrix and multiplying it with the given B how can i prove your statement ?